# Creating an alternative keyboard for UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, keyboard

I have a note taking app. I want to add my own custom keyboard for user input. My app uses UIWebView. When app opens, a UIwebview loads index.html file that contains a content editable div. 
I made a keyboard with javascript and when index.html is loaded, my keyboard (actually a table with buttons) shows and ios keyboard disappears.

I am hiding ios keyboard with this function

```
UIView *v=[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
v.hidden=true;
```

I wonder will apple approve my app? I couldn't find anything says this is wrong? I just want to add my own keyboard to my app? UIWebView loads only my html file for note taking.

Comment: nothing wrong with this approach, as far as it follow the guideline.  it clearly written that *you can design a custom input view to replace the system-provided onscreen keyboard.*. i think your app should be approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guidelines says

```
If appropriate, you can design a custom input view to replace the system-provided onscreen keyboard.
```

So I guess, there should not be any issue. You can find more informations [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/KeyboardInputView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH48-SW1).